# Why I can't install apps in my phone even sufficient space is available?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, motorola, adobe-reader

So I own Moto E 1 gen, running now Android 4.4 stock

I tried to install Adobe reader,Jiotv I end up with a message "Out of space"

I used both ways,APK and Playstore both ways don't work. 
Although I could install  big games and apps I could not install few selected apps like Jiotv and Adobe Reader and some few..

I formatted my phone twice, Cleared cached memory.Still it says out of space.I did everything right and still my phone got issues. The phone is rooted, running on stock ROM.

[image: Jiotv app error]
[image: system memory]
[image: Adobe reader Out of space error]
[image: some apps are installing properly even games like sniper fury].

I don't know what is the problem. With Adobe reader and Jiotv apps

Do u have solution or cause of problem ?

Comment: Have you investigated the suggestions within the hundreds of similar [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=out+of+space+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) here? Please explore suggestions made by others, and amplify your post with the dissimilarities requiring your unique solution.

Comment: I see that you are using Link2sd, which if I remember correctly had an option of changing default download location to external SD. All apps don't support this. Change the download location to internal and update of it is solved

Comment: Please mention the capacity and free space in both internal and external SD. There are apps like Disk usage and Disk info using which post a screen shot of internal SD

Comment: Its my internal is 1.3GB free and 5 GB extrenal SD card.